# Power analysis for RSA (representational similarity analysis)?

Tags: r

I submitted my paper to a journal and the editor asked me to report the smallest possible effect size that can be detected with my sample size (two matched groups, 31 participants in each group). one of our main analysis was representational similarity analysis (RSA). In our RSA, we correlate individual responses within each group (x and y) and evaluate the similarity of these correlation matrices (reference models) with predicted data patterns (conceptual models). Conceptual models were based on possible predicted patterns for 3 variables (VAR1, VAR2 and VAR3). For example, for VAR 1, where there are two categories of interest, the values of the conceptual model will be ‘1’ for stimuli that are of the same category, and ‘0’ for stimuli that are not of the same category.
 Then, two multiple regression analyses were performed, one with the reference model of group x and another one with the reference model of group y as dependent variables. The three conceptual models were used as independent variables to estimate to what degree VAR1, VAR2, and VAR3 contributed to group x and y reference models. 
As far as I understand, for the power analysis of RSA I need to do Monte Carlo simulation; However, calculating power analysis for RSA does not look straight forward. Has anybody experience in this area or can point me to literature that contemplates this issue? Suggestions for relevant literature and R code greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is a question about statistical method, maybe you should ask it in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @mhvelplund
Thank you, I will do.